# Is there such a thing as an actual 60W draw LED or CFL bulb?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, cfl

CFL and LED lightbulbs are sold as being "40/60/100 watt *equivalent*". They're designed and sold as replacements for a certain wattage of incandescent lamp.

I have some fixtures where I want a very bright bulb. Since CFLs and LEDs can get more light out of less wattage it seems to me that an actual 40W draw CFL or LED that would be significantly brighter than a 40W incandescent.

Does such a super-CFL or super-LED lamp exist?

Comment: I think a CFL that actually draws 40W, would be equivalent to a 150W incandescent bulb (>2600 lumens). Not sure you'll find anything brighter, or even a CFL that bright for that matter.

Comment: Just a note that because CFLs have a power factor of around 0.5, a 40W CFL will draw about twice as much current as a 40W incandescent bulb.  Your fixture may not be rated to handle this.

Comment: @Tester101 comment helped me discover the right search pattern. It seems to be expressed as "X-watt (Y-watt replacement)" at a major online retailer. The bulbs to avoid for my use case are ones which are "40-watt equivalent"

Comment: an LED that consumes 60 watts will blind you. that would be the equivalent to 600-700 watts that an incandescent light would produce.

Comment: @SkipBerne - Yep, be aware what you ask for, you can get a permanent retinal burn off an 8 watt LED array. Wattage is no longer the true measure but lumens.

Comment: Shop lumens, not watts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for lights with a high lumen output.  Since LED/CFL bulbs don't convert heat to light, the wattage isn't directly proportional to the light output.  As an extreme example, consider that a 2 watt laser is powerful enough to burn some materials, or blind you!

What you'll likely find is that more expensive LED bulbs from lighting specialty stores are brighter than the cheap bulbs you find at your local home improvement store.

There are other characteristics of the bulb other than power which impact the perceived brightness - reflectors are a good example.  A bulb with a wide spread will seem less bright (in a room) than a bulb with a narrow spread since the light is being diffused more.

Comment: All lamps have inefficiency and will produce heat. Incandescent, halogen, CFL, and LED bulbs convert 98%, 97%, 91%, 88% of their electric consumption into heat, respectively. An ideal (no heat) "60 watt" / 800 lumen bulb would consume only about 1 watt of electricity.

Comment: ...sorry I thought you said "LED/CFL bulbs don't create heat". My comment isn't really relevant in light of what you actually said!

Comment: I meant that they are not heating a filament to produce light...

Comment: A low-wattage laser can burn you because those the energy is focused into such a small area.  I don't see how that's relevant to the wattage of LED/CFL bulbs at all.

Comment: if you capture **all** the light AND heat from a 2-watt bulb and focus it to a small point it would burn, too

Answer (score 0):

Sure there are. Here's a 45-watter:

[image]

and that's what you get when you open the box:

[image]

They're not even specialty items (although that depends on where you live. I moved to Amsterdam a while ago and here I just can't find anything over 20W, except for the elongated T4/T5 tubes).