# Can I use a CFL or LED bulb with a higher lumen output as long as I stay under the maximum wattage listed on the fixture?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, bulb

I have a light fixture that lists the maximum bulb wattage as 60W. Right now, I have a standard incandescent bulb in place. Since there is only one light in the room, a single bulb is not bright enough.  Can I safely switch to CFLs or LEDs with a greater Lumen output than the standard 60 incandescent as long as I don't go over the 60W draw?

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/64107/is-there-such-a-thing-as-an-actual-60w-draw-led-or-cfl-bulb - Related question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The more efficient bulb will also produce less heat, so it should be fine. The only concern is that if there is a dimmer you need a dimmable bulb, and if there is a touch switch or other circuit that was powering itself via a trickle current thru the bulb that may not work -- but neither it nor the bulb will be harmed by the experiment, so go for it.

Comment: Frequently, cfls and leds need the newer dimmers,otherwise low dimmer settings result.  Again, not dangerous, just annoying to have to replace both.

Comment: Older bulbs yes. Newer leds are more tolerant.